# Xcode 6 auto layout flexible width

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6

I have a UITextField which using Xcode 6s auto layout interface I have set to have a width of 400 points. This looks fine on larger screen devices but on the iPhone 5s these boxes disappear out of the containing view. What is the correct way to approach this?

Is there a way to set a constraint that will make the UITextFields width 400 points if the screen is large than this or just fill the container view if not, instead of overflowing outside of the view or should I be using the size classes to set the UITextField to have equal widths to its parent view on compact views.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the width constraint on the UITextField, add Horizontal Space constraints to the left and right of it. That way the UITextField will size automatically with the screen.

Comment: The only issue I have with that is for large screen devices like iPads I do not want the text view taking up the full screen as it will look silly.

Comment: The recommended approach by apple would be to have different storyboards/xibs for iphone and ipad. They code would be fully shared.

Comment: @KrisJurgowski It seems like Apple is wanting to push us to combined Storyboard files with different implementations per size class. I'm not sure I care for that tool/approach just yet, but it seems to be the wave of the future. I hope they make it easier to differentiate devices/screens, though. Right now, it's fairly easy to differentiate an iPhone from an iPad, but differentiating an iPhone 4S from an iPhone 6 Plus is confusing (at least in portrait mode). For now, I'm with you about separate Storyboards, but I don't think that will be supported for very much longer.

Comment: It works, thanks, I want to know, why need to add Horizontal Space constraints ? I think left and right constraints is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Like what Kris said, setting up Horizontal Space constraints is a great way to get started on this issue.

In response to your comment about not wanting constant "margins", you can do the following:

1. Set up Horizontal Space constraints in Interface Builder.
2. Create `IBOutlet`s of type `NSLayoutConstraint` in your class (either .h or .m; it doesn't matter).
3. Connect the `IBOutlet`s to the respective `NSLayoutConstraint`s.
4. In one of your view lifecycle methods (`viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear:`), set up the constraints to your desired values.

It sounds like you mainly want to prevent the field from spanning the full screen on an iPad, so you could do something like this (assume `NSLayoutConstraint`s are named "textFieldLeft" and "textFieldRight" for a `UITextField` named "textField"):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.textFieldLeft.constant = 50.0f;
        self.textFieldRight.constant = 50.0f;
        [self.textField layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```